# Specify a root path for imports?

Tags: vue.js

I'm converting my ongoing Vue.js app over to use vue-cli/Webpack and imported modules Something I'm finding rather tedious at the moment is specifying the relative paths for imports accurately. E.g. `import bus from '../../bus'`, `import Cell from '../Cell'`. Easy to make a mistake.

I'm assuming it must be straightforward enough to specify a base or root directory and specify absolute paths from that, but I can't see where one would do that. For example, in the standard vue-cli webpack setup, the code I'm working on is all in the 'src' directory, inside which I have 'components', 'mixins', etc. It would be handy if I could use `import xxx from 'components/xxx'`, `import yyy from 'components/a/yyy'`. How would I do that?

Comment: not sure how exactly you have to do that, but looks like you would need to do it in webpack conf and some 'solve'

Comment: It actually seems as if there is already provision for this using resolve.alias in the webpack.base.conf.js file. Aliases are defined for 'components' and 'src', which seem to work.

Comment: good. Glad I gave you good lead

Answer (score 26):

With vue-cli, you put webpack settings in vue-config.js, in the same folder as package.json.

vue-config.js:

```
var path = require('path')
module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias: {
        src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
      }
    },
  }
}
```

This will allow you to do

```
import HelloWorld from 'src/components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

instead of

```
import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

See https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#vue-config-js for more info.

Comment: For your example you can create an alias directly to components as well.

Comment: Please note that in the current iteration of Vue this file is `vue.config.js` not `vue-config.js` as suggested here :)

Comment: how to make this work with assets?. For the src in <img>

Answer (score 21):

The solution is already in place, in fact, just not well-documented. In `webpack.base.conf.js`, there is this:

```
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.vue', '.json'],
    fallback: [path.join(__dirname, '../node_modules')],
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.common.js',
      'src': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src'),
      'assets': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/assets'),
      'components': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/components')
    }
  }
```

I've added my own alias, `'mixins': path.resolve(__dirname, '../src/mixins')`. So I can now use e.g. `import Field from 'mixins/Field'`, along with e.g. `import ScrollableTable from 'components/ScrollableTable'`.

Comment: I added this to the `webpack.config.js` file for anybody using one

Answer (score 21):

I am using laravel and the laravel-mix package.

To make it work add this to your webpack.mix.js :

```js
const path = require('path');

mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, 'resources/js')
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: I think this is the best solution.

Comment: Work like a charm. What does `const path = require('path');` actually require? Thanks!

Comment: here is a link to the doc of 'path' module:  https://nodejs.org/api/path.html

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work (using Laravel 8.x). The docs suggest using `path.join` instead of `path.resolve`.  That worked for me.  

https://laravel-mix.com/docs/6.0/aliases

Answer (score 15):

You can use something like this:

```
import { routes } from '@/router/routes'
```

where `/router` folder is on the root of my project and I can import my routes anywhere :)

Note: I'm using VueJS 2.0

Comment: Well this is not really the answer, as it does not magically work.
See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack to setup the @ resolver

Comment: This works but what about SCSS in a single file component?

Answer (score 2):

Create a vue.config.js file at the project root that will contain

```js
var path = require('path');
module.exports = {
 configureWebpack : {
  resolve: {
         modules : [
          path.resolve("./src"),
             path.resolve("./node_modules")
         ]
     },
 }
}
```

Comment: You saved my life, Thanks. [I was looking for the answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70858847/import-dependency-from-child-folder-node-modules-doesnt-work)

Answer (score 1):

Just use @ symbol as root in the path for the import.
For example, let's say you have a **firebase** folder under root and a **firebaseConfig.js**
file like this

```
// Your web app's Firebase configuration

var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "...somekey...",
  authDomain: "...someApp....firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://...someApp....firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "...someProjId...",
  storageBucket: "",
  ...bla bla bla...  
};
export default firebaseConfig;
```

in the **firebase** folder.

You can import the config file anywhere using the following instruction:

```
import firebaseConfig from '@/firebase/firebaseConfig'
```

Answer (score 1):

Create **vue.config.js** file on the root directory

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = defineConfig({
    configureWebpack: {
       resolve: {
          alias: {
             src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
          }
       }
    }
})
```

Once after done with the configuration. We can now able to target the file inside **src** directory using below import statement.

```
import About from src/component/About.vue
```

If you have another main folder inside the src directory. You can achieve by using the below command.

```
package: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src/package')
```

Answer (score 0):

Late answer: To create an alias for all folders inside src. Uses Damian Helme solution. All credits should go to him.

Allows you to import:

```
import HelloWorld from 'components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

From:

```
import HelloWorld from '../components/HelloWorld.vue'
```

Create **vue.config.js** on the root folder of the project. Note: Doesn't automatically update when new folders are created, you will need to manually restart.

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//Find all files in src and make alias

const dirs  = fs.readdirSync(path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'));

const alias = {
  src: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src')
}

dirs.forEach(name => {
  const filePath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', name);
  //Only add folders
  if (fs.statSync(filePath).isDirectory()) {
      alias[name] = filePath;
  }
  
});

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      alias
    },
  }
}
```