# Is there any option to namespace a module folder path in angular 2-5?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular5

Is there any way to use namespace for custom paths in Angular 5?
Currently I use

```
import { AuthService } from './../../modules/auth/auth.service';
```

What I am trying to achieve is using `@module` or custom `@name` for a particular path. The code should look like below and be usable in every folder level

```
import { AuthService } from '@modules/auth/auth.service';
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ES6 import using at ('@') sign in path in a vue.js project using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, there is `paths` property in `tsconfig.json` configuration:

```
{
   ...
   "compilerOptions": {
       ...
       "paths": {
           "@core/*": ["app/core/*"],
           "@shared/*": ["app/shared/*"]
    }      
}
```

Comment: This did the trick , all is working but my Vs-code IDE shows error on line.. know any workaround for this?

Comment: Not sure, my IDE reads these paths and knows how to handle it.There is a bug open: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/8138
Maybe search a bit more to find out if other people have this problem?

Comment: Fixed it.. i was using '@module' for importing all exported members instead i used '@module/index'