# Neutrinojs/vue project: Importing vue files/templates from root folder

Tags: node.js, webpack, vue.js, import, neutrino

I want to import starting from the root folder, not go several folders down.
How do I do that?

I come across this issue while trying to import a guestbook (like it's 1999) script for my homepage.

`import MyGuestbook from '../../components/MyGuestbook.vue'` compiles.

`import MyGuestbook from '/src/components/MyGuestbook.vue'` doesn't.

`import MyGuestbook from '@/components/MyGuestbook.vue'` doesn't either.

*GuestBookPage.vue*

```
<template>
<div>
    <MyGuestbook />
</div>
</template>

<script>
import MyGuestbook from '../../components/MyGuestbook.vue'

export default {
  name: 'GuestbookPage',
  components: {
    MyGuestbook
  }
};
</script>
```

*MyGuestbook.vue*

```
<template>
  </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script src="non-editable-comments-v0.1.0.js"></script>
<script>
  window.safeComments('CommentTitle', 'CommentTargetID');

  export default {
    name: 'MyGuestbook'
  };
</script>
```

[update]

I understand that I need to use webpack, but my project uses neutrinojs/vue (Recommended for the type of project) in combination with webpack. I'm not familiar with either of them. So far adding a *webpack.config.js* has not worked.

*webpack.config.js*

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    extensions: [
      '.js', '.vue', '.json'
    ],
    alias: {
      '@': resolve('src'),
      '@root': resolve('.')
    }
  }
};
```

Nor has editing *.neutrinorc.js*

```
module.exports = {
  use: [
    '@neutrinojs/standardjs',
    [
      '@neutrinojs/vue',
      {
        html: {
          title: 'MySite'
        }
      }
    ],
    '@neutrinojs/jest',
    (neutrino) => {
      neutrino.config.resolve.extensions
        .add('.js')
        .add('.json')
        .add('.vue');

      neutrino.config.resolve.alias
      .set('@', 'src')
      .set('@root', '.');
    }
  ]
};
```

the error:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/@neutrinojs/compile-loader/node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,
"plugins":[["/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/fast-async/plugin.js",
{"spec":true}],
"/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
"/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js"],
"presets":[["/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js",
{"debug":false,"modules":false,
"useBuiltIns":true,"exclude":["transform-regenerator",
"transform-async-to-generator"],
"targets":{"browsers":[
"last 2 Chrome versions",
"last 2 Firefox versions",
"last 2 Edge versions",
"last 2 Opera versions",
"last 2 Safari versions",
"last 2 iOS versions"]}}]]}!.
/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/docs/7.forum/GuestbookPage.vue
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/YroGuestbook.vue' in '/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/src/docs/7.forum'
 @ ./node_modules/@neutrinojs/compile-loader/node_modules/babel-loader/lib?{"cacheDirectory":true,
"plugins":[["/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/fast-async/plugin.js",
{"spec":true}],
"/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-plugin-syntax-dynamic-import/lib/index.js",
"/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-object-rest-spread/lib/index.js"],
"presets":[["/home/folatt/Cloud/workspace/atom/Sites/MySite/node_modules/babel-preset-env/lib/index.js",
{"debug":false,"modules":false,"useBuiltIns":true,
"exclude":["transform-regenerator","transform-async-to-generator"],
"targets":{"browsers":["last 2 Chrome versions",
"last 2 Firefox versions",
"last 2 Edge versions",
"last 2 Opera versions",
"last 2 Safari versions",
"last 2 iOS versions"]}}]]}!.
/node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/docs/7.forum/GuestbookPage.vue 8:0-57
 @ ./src/docs/7.forum/GuestbookPage.vue
 @ ./src/router/index.js
 @ ./src/index.js
 @ multi ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:5000 ./node_modules/@neutrinojs/web/node_modules/webpack/hot/dev-server.js ./src/index
```

Comment: It may depend on the template you've used (if any), but `@` is usually used as an alias for `src`, so you can reference like this: `from '@/components/MyGuesbook.vue'` [ES6 import using at ('@') sign in path in a vue.js project using Webpack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack)

Comment: Template? You mean neutrinojs/vue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed the whole babel-plugin thing.

```
yarn add babel-plugin-root-import -dev
```

*.babelrc*

```
{
  "plugins": [
    ["babel-plugin-root-import", {
      "rootPathSuffix": "src",
      "rootPathPrefix": "@"
    }]
  ]
}
```

I couldn't get the alias resolves to work, but this **does** seem to work.