# Package vue components that use class syntax

Tags: vuejs2, vue-cli-3

I have a hard time packaging our components as an npm package so we can reuse them in other projects.
I have the feeling I  searched everywhere on the internet to no avail. I'm suspecting that using our components in the class syntax style makes most, if not even all, examples fail for me.
The final and most successful so far was the one from the [Vue documentation](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/packaging-sfc-for-npm.html)
However with that one I get an error:

```
[!] (buble plugin) SyntaxError: Unexpected character '@'
```

The reason for that is obviously the class syntax with @Component immediately failing the build. Is there a way to make this work with class syntax?

My component's script part looks like this (nothing special on the css and template parts):

```
<script>
import { Vue, Component, Prop } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Checkbox extends Vue {
  @Prop({default: false}) checked;

};
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I think that the problem is with installing `vue-loader` and `vue-template-compiler` together.

I'm *Quoting*  [Vue-loader Vue Docs](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/#manual-setup)

> **The plugin is required!** It is responsible for cloning any other rules
>   you have defined and applying them to the corresponding language
>   blocks in `.vue` files. For example, if you have a rule matching
>   `/\.js$/`, it will be applied to `<script>` blocks in `.vue` files.

After you `npm install` them, you need to change your `webpack.config.js` file like this

```js
const VueLoaderPlugin = require('vue-loader/lib/plugin')

module.exports = {
  module: {
    rules: [
      // ... other rules
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        loader: 'vue-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    // make sure to include the plugin!
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly Vue does use Webpack internally. A `vue inspect > output.js` command shows that the `VueLoaderPlugin` is actually included already. I guess that is because we are using the CLI?

Comment: take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack

Comment: Sorry, but I don't see anything in that question that helps me :-(