# How to define socket variable globally

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, hapi.js

I have this piece of code in my `socketio` file and here I can use `socket` simply.

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  var io = require('socket.io')(server.listener)
  io.on('connection', async(socket) => {
    // here I can use socket.emit() and all
  })
  next()
}

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'socket'
}
```

Now, I need to use the`io` socket to `emit` events from various files and don't want to connect this `io.on('connection', async(socket) => {})` every time.

How can I do this?

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 6):

`next` callback doesn't serve a good purpose here because it's synchronous. Since socket.io `connection` event can be triggered multiple times, it cannot be converted to a promise for easier chaining, so it's better for it to stay callback-based.

It can be:

```
var socketIo = require('socket.io')

exports.register = (server, options) => {
  var io = socketIo(server.listener);

  return onConnect => {
    io.on('connection', onConnect);
  };
}
```

So connection function is created once:

```
const myConnection = register(myServer);
```

And used through the application:

```
myConnection(client => {
  ...
});
```

This situation can also benefit from observables, e.g. RxJS.

In case the socket shouldn't support reconnections, this could be simplified to:

```
exports.register = (server, options) => {
  var io = socketIo(server.listener);

  return new Promise(resolve => {        
    io.once('connection', resolve);
  });
}
```

Connection promise is created once:

So connection function is created once:

```
const myConnection = register(myServer);
```

And used through the application:

```
const client = await myConnection;
...
```

Comment: Thankyou!!! But still I have to use callback with the `myConnection`? As I already registered it inside my socket file.?

Comment: **This question is unrelated, though I was able to answer it, so I've tried to do this** ok thank you estus you for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. Yes, there should be a callback because `connection` event can be triggered multiple times because a socket can be reconnected. In case you don't need reconnections, you could promisify `io.once('connection', ...)` and use `async..await` to chain a promise

Comment: Cool. If you can show how can I use `async` `await` here that would be great.

Comment: I updated. I wouldn't recommend that, unless you're certain that you won't ever need reconnections.

Comment: I only need connection at the first(when app starts). BTW I haven't tested the above solution but I am sure it will work. Thank you once again!!!

Comment: It is not entering inside the `return onConnect => {
    io.on('connection', onConnect);
  }`?

Comment: How so? The only possibility for `return onConnect => {
    io.on('connection', onConnect);
  };` to not work is to not call this function. If the function is called, it should work.

Comment: Sorry Estus but it does not work :-(. it is hapi server. And register function calls inside manifest but I can see connection is not established. The above code gives me the error `TypeError: (0 , _index.default) is not a function
`. Please test it if you can with hapijs.

Comment: I can't test it with Hapi but I don't think that Hapi is the problem here. The error likely means that something is wrong with imports and exports.

Comment: Please, add your current attempt to the question because the error you described seems to be caused by wrong import/export code. `_index.default` suggests that `default` import was used from `index` module but there's no `default` export.

Answer (score 2):

You can share functionality across your server instance with [Server methods](https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/blob/master/API.md#server.methods)

```
import _ from 'lodash'
import mongoose from 'mongoose'

exports.register = (server, options, next) => {
  var io = require('socket.io')(server.listener)
  io.on('connection', async(socket) => {
    // here I can use socket.emit() and all
  })
  // here use server methods
  server.decorate('server', 'io', io);
  next()
}

exports.register.attributes = {
  name: 'socket'
}
```

Then in your controller

```
handler: function (request, reply) {
        const io = request.server.io;

    }
```