# what is '@' in import reference, and why it doesn't work in VSCode

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code

In my `router/index.js` I have a reference that looks like that:

`import SingleVignette from '@/components/Vignette'`

I guess `@` stays for a base directory, right? But I try to Command+click on the reference in VSCode it doesn't refer me to an original file (while `../components/Vignette` does. How to make it work?

Comment: This SO thread should sort out your query
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/es6-import-using-at-sign-in-path-in-a-vue-js-project-using-webpack