# Issue when I try to use lazyload with vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Hi I am trying to use lazyload with VueJs my code is this one:

```
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
function lazyLoad(view){
  return() => import(`../views/${view}.vue`)
}  
export default new VueRouter({
  mode: 'history',
  base: process.env.BASE_URL,
  routes: [
   {
     path: '/account',
     name: 'account',
     component: lazyLoad('Account')
   }
 ]
});
```

When I do this, it displays this error:

```
ERROR in ./resources/js/assets/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views' in '/home/jysparki/public_html/resources/js/assets'
@ ./resources/js/assets/router.js 7:11-51
@ ./resources/js/app.js
@ multi ./resources/js/app.js ./resources/sass/app.scss
```

whot could the problem be?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error code says

```
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../views'
```

This means that your relative directory in `return() => import('../views/${view}.vue')` is not correct. Correct your relative directory and it will work.

For example `return() => import('@/views/${view}.vue')` should work assuming that your folder structure is the default

```
+ src
|--+ Assets 
|--+ Components
|--+ Views
```

Because `@` is a reference to `/src` therefore `@/Assets` is the same as `/src/Assets` thanks to webpack's resolve feature. https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/2073738

Comment: I did that but it displays: 
ERROR in ./resources/js/assets/router.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/views/${view}.vue' in '/home/jysparki/public_html/resources/js/assets'
 @ ./resources/js/assets/router.js 7:11-40

Comment: I wonder where is that src? Because I see the folders and I can not find it I just see js/assets, js/components

Comment: Without knowing your project structure, I cannot tell you more than that. The issue is that the `views` folder is not found. In this answer I am assuming that you are using vue-cli to generate your project. If you can provide us with more information about your project and how it is structured, and if you are using vue-cli or not that would be useful

Comment: I create a folder in js/views and it worked TY!