# webpack - cannot resolve the file

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, webpack, vuejs2

When I run `npm run build`, below error occurs.

```
ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 9:0-51
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '../components/header/index.js' in 'MyProject/src'
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-157 1:173-176 1:178-332 1:178-332
 @ ./src/App.vue 2:0-55 3:0-50 3:0-50 10:2-8
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-28 29:13-16

ERROR in ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js??vue-loader-options!./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&) 10:0-50
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/components/footer/index.js' in 'MyProject/src'
 @ ./src/App.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js& 1:0-157 1:173-176 1:178-332 1:178-332
 @ ./src/App.vue 2:0-55 3:0-50 3:0-50 10:2-8
 @ ./src/main.js 3:0-28 29:13-16

ERROR in ./src/main.js 6:0-33
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@/assets/scss/main.scss' in 'MyProject/src'
```

package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config build/webpack.config.dev.js"
  },
```

build/webpack.config.dev.js

```
'use strict'

const webpack = require('webpack')
const { VueLoaderPlugin } = require('vue-loader');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: [
    './src/main.js'
  ],
  devServer: {
    hot: true,
    watchOptions: {
      poll: true
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: 'vue-loader'
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          'vue-style-loader',
          'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: 'babel-loader'
      }
    ]
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new VueLoaderPlugin(),
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      filename: 'index.html',
      template: 'index.html',
      inject: true
    })
  ]
}
```

src/App.vue

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
     <Header />
    <router-view />
    <Footer/>
  </div>
</template>

<script type="text/javascript">
import Header from "@/components/header/index.js";
import Footer from "@/components/footer/index.js";

export default {
  components: {
    Header,
    Footer
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss">
@import "@/assets/scss/main.scss";
</style>
```

How to solve it?

Comment: Why aren't you using Vue CLI? It's much simpler...

Comment: @Capt 171 I am already under development stage. Is there any way to add webpack afterward?

Comment: I thought you were already using Webpack? You could also try building with Vue CLI

Comment: just use vite and forget about this

Comment: @Emīls Gulbis my project is ongoing. Is there any way to add webpack in it?

Comment: dont use webpack, check vite.js

Comment: You are using @/ which frees you from using paths relative to the file you import other files. But you have to configure that alias in your webpack config. That’s why your paths can‘t be resolved I guess

Comment: Look here how to config: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/4584472