# How to display images with Vue?

Tags: javascript, image, vue.js

I am using Vue and my image paths are not working. I have tried these different variations:

```
<figure class="workout-image">
            <img :src= "images.bicep" width= "200px" length= "300px">
            <figcaption>Bicep Curl</figcaption>
          </figure>
        
         <figure class="workout-image">
            <img :src= "'https://thumbs.dreamstime.com/z/bench-press-exercise-chest-man-doing-workout-bench-press-exercise-chest-man-doing-workout-barbell-bodybuilder-157558597.jpg'" width= "200px" length= "300px">
            <figcaption>Bench Press</figcaption>
          </figure>

          <figure class="workout-image">
            <img v-bind:src= "'../assets/images/workouts/TricepExtension.png'" width= "200px" length= "300px">
            <figcaption>Tricep Extension</figcaption>
          </figure>
```

I have my images in my src/assets folder and the full path is src/assets/images/workouts. I always get a little icon not displaying the image.
[image not showing up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P6ECG.png)

edit: I do not put anything in the  tag

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have your assets folder in your `src` folder, vue-loader should load them in for you, and you can access them using `@/assets/rest/of/path`.

```
<figure class="workout-image">
    <img src="@/assets/images/workouts/TricepExtension.png" width= "200px" length= "300px">
    <figcaption>Bicep Curl</figcaption>
</figure>
```

See [this section about vue asset url handling](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/asset-url.html#transform-rules)

Comment: The image still does not show up.

Comment: Does your webpack file have a `resolve` section like you see in the picture in this question? (Check the top answer) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/what-does-the-mean-inside-an-import-path