# "Cannot resolve directory '@'" in WebStorm for a Vue file

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

I'm using WebStorm 2021.2.4, and when I create a Vue.js 3 app I have this error:

[image]

It looks like the IDE cannot identify `@` as the root directory `src`. How can I solve this?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/11260991) answer your question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vite, as well as [vite aliases](https://vitejs.dev/config/#resolve-alias), is not yet supported. Please feel free to vote for [WEB-53634](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-53634) and linked tickets. Actually we can hardly afford supporting all possible ways to define path mappings coming from different bundlers, frameworks and plugins. In the future we'd likely provide some unified way to deal with them in the IDE. For now, I can only suggest creating a dummy `config.js` file with all aliases specified explicitly like

```
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, "src/"] ,
      ...
    },
  },
};
```

and then set the webpack configuration to **Manual** in **Settings | Languages & Frameworks | JavaScript | Webpack** and specify a full path to this dummy config there

Comment: I cannot get the workaround working whatever I try. I also don't find any useful hints in the `idea.log`. Oddly enough, `import ... from "@/..." or `"@/..."` in `<template>` works out of the box (i.e. no errors, can jump to). Any ideas?

Answer (score 8):

To fix **"Cannot resolve directory '@'"** in **PHPStorm 11 for Vue 3.2, Vite 2.9, Laravel 9 & TS**

Please check if in root folder of your project a `tsconfig.json` file exists. If not, create it and add the following code:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "baseUrl": "./resources",
        "paths": {
            "@/*": ["js/*"]
        }
    },
    "include": [
        "env.d.ts",
        "resources/js/**/*",
    ],
}
```

If you don't use typescript, just create `jsconfig.json` version.

Comment: In my legacy project, It's using "@router/layouts/main". So, in `compilerOptions.paths` if I use `"@*"` it works perfectly fine.