# Vue 3, TypeScript & Pinia compability - ERROR: cannot find module

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, pinia

Trying Vue 3 with TS & Pinia. Inside a component, everything is fine with  but when I try , I'm gettings an error in VS Code: "Cannot find Module @/stores/todoList".

The same error with "import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'" : Cannot find 'pinia'.

```
<script setup  lang="ts">
import { useTodoListStore } from '@/stores/todoList'
import { storeToRefs } from 'pinia'
</script>
```

My Store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia'

export const useTodoListStore = defineStore("todoList", {
  state: () => ({
    todoList: [],
    id: 0
  }),
  actions: {
    addTodo(item) {
      this.todoList.push({ item, id: this.id++, completed: false })
    },
    deleteTodo(itemId) {
      this.todoList = this.todoList.filter((object) => {
        return object.id !== itemId
      })
    },
    toggleCompleted(idToFind) {
      const todo = this.todoList.find((obj) => obj.id === idToFind)
      if (todo) {
        todo.completed = !todo.completed
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you don't have the project properly configured to support the use of the `@` syntax. There are two ways past this: changing your configuration, or not using the `@` syntax.

### Method One

You can change the import to be a typical relative path import for a simple fix, just use something along the lines of the following, depending on your file's location:

```js
import { useTodoListStore } from '../../stores/todoList'
```

### Method Two

#### tsconfig

If you want to enable the use of the `@` syntax, you can do it from within your `tsconfig` file, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55764326/6456163):

```json
"paths": {
  "@": ["src"],
}
```

#### webpack

Or from within your Webpack configuration file via `resolve.alias`, as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42753045/6456163):

```js
const path = require('path');

...
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.vue', '.json'],
  alias: {
    ...
    '@': path.resolve('src'),
  }
},
...
```

Comment: Vite has some config as well. Non of this resolved the issue.  Something between TS 


`export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url))
    }
  }
})`

Comment: I think it is hung up on the export const.

`export const useTodoListStore`