# Unable to import an exported type

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have a bunch of generated Typscript files. I am able to successfully import the `interface` that I have needed so far. But now I need to import a `type` but I keep getting an error:

```js
import {
  _rpc_SystemLogMessage_LogLevel as LogLevel,
  _rpc_SystemLogMessage_SubSystem as SubSystem
} from '@/rpc/SystemLogMessage'
```

> Cannot find module '@/rpc/SystemLogMessage' from 'tests/clients/session.test.ts'

This file defines the following:

```js
export const _rpc_SystemLogMessage_LogLevel = {
  ERROR: 0,
  WARNING: 1,
  INFO: 2,
  DEBUG: 3,
} as const;

export type _rpc_SystemLogMessage_LogLevel =
  | 'ERROR'
  | 0
  | 'WARNING'
  | 1
  | 'INFO'
  | 2
  | 'DEBUG'
  | 3
```

This is how my `tsconfig.json`

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2017",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["./compiled/*"]
    }
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

Please note that I have a bunch of files in the same directory that I have been able to import other interfaces from. I'm not sure what is different from this file that I am having trouble importing a simple `type` definition.

Comment: what's your directory structure? From the error message there is clearly an issue with the filepath.

Comment: @RobinZigmond that's weird because I have other files in the same directory that I am getting a bunch of interfaces from and they work just fine. But if you really want to know, the directory structure is `<root>/compiled/rpc/SystemLogMessage.ts`.

Comment: Thanks. I looked at this in a bit more detail - including [needing a Stack Overflow question to understand what your @ path meant](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42749973/what-does-the-mean-inside-an-import-path), but it seems you've set this in your tsconfig to reference a *relative path* starting `./`, rather than an absolute path as would be more normal. So this will presumably only work from other files inside the root directory, which your `tests/client` directory is not.