# import dependency from child_folder/node_modules doesn't work

Tags: laravel, webpack, node-modules, laravel-mix

By default `node_modules` folder is under the root directory of my Laravel project and it's working fine. I can compile the scripts with `npm run dev` and there is no error.

However according to the project folder structure, I move `node_modules` folder into a child folder called `backend`.

> Here, I also moved the files like `webpack.mix.js`, `package.json` into backend folder and `run npm install` again inside it. But I keep my `resources` and `public` folders as original and link them with relative path via `backend` folder.

The folder structure looks like this

[image]

Now, if I run `npm run dev` inside `backend` folder, it complains many errors like `can't resolve '@babel/runtime/regenerator'`.

But if I make a symbolic `node_modules` inside root folder which is linked to `backend/node_modules`, it works fine and I can compile the scripts without error.

[image]

My question is - How can I compile the scripts from child folder without making a symbolic like this?
Probably it doesn't know where `node_modules` folder is located.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As laravel-mix is based on webpack. I add the `modules` path inside webpack config as below to make all `import` knows where the `node_modules` folder is located.

```js
mix.webpackConfig({
  resolve: {
    modules : [
        path.resolve("./node_modules")
    ]
  }
});
```

There is no more `can't resolve` error.

Comment: As of Laravel 9,  MIX has been deprecated in favor of Vite. Still looking for the new way of doing this.

`Vite has replaced Laravel Mix in new Laravel installations. For Mix documentation, please visit the official Laravel Mix website. If you would like to switch to Vite, please see our Vite migration guide.`