# How can I solve "These relative modules were not found:" problem on a Vue app deploying on netlify?

Tags: vue.js, module, netlify

I am trying to deploy my app to netlify but my build fails... Why?

My main.js file looks like that and if I run locally yarn build then I see no errors, only in netlify!

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import './plugins/axios'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')
```

```
11:51:28 PM:  ERROR  Failed to compile with 4 errors8:51:28 PM
11:51:28 PM: These relative modules were not found:
11:51:28 PM: * ./plugins/axios in ./src/main.js
11:51:28 PM: * ./plugins/vuetify in ./src/main.js
11:51:28 PM: * ./router/index in ./src/main.js
11:51:28 PM: * ./store/index in ./src/main.js
11:51:28 PM:  ERROR  Build failed with errors.
11:51:28 PM: ​
11:51:28 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:51:28 PM:   "build.command" failed                                        
11:51:28 PM: ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
11:51:28 PM: ​
11:51:28 PM:   Error message
11:51:28 PM:   Command failed with exit code 1: npm run build (https://ntl.fyi/exit-code-1)
11:51:28 PM: ​
11:51:28 PM:   Error location
11:51:28 PM:   In Build command from Netlify app:
11:51:28 PM:   npm run build
11:51:28 PM: ​
11:51:28 PM:   Resolved config
11:51:28 PM:   build:
```

Comment: It's because you're using relative modules. If you can specify absolute paths, or better still use aliases then it will work on any system no matter from where it's started from.

Comment: @Lissy93 can you give an example?

Comment: It will also depend on your project structure, are you using Webpack?

Comment: If I were you, I'd set up aliases - [here's how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52648570/979052).